# RegularExp for image url

Tags: php, regex

I want te replace all image links on image tags, but I don't know what I'm doing wrong.

Here is my regex: `/(http:\/\/.+(png|jpeg|jpg|gif|bmp))/i`

But when i use it with string: `http://re-actor.net/uploads/posts/2009-08/1249921580_toyota-ft-hs.png and http://re-actor.net/uploads/posts/2009-08/thumbs/1249922220_toyota_ft-hs-14.jpg`

Result is `<img src="http://re-actor.net/uploads/posts/2009-08/1249921580_toyota-ft-hs.png and http://re-actor.net/uploads/posts/2009-08/thumbs/1249922220_toyota_ft-hs-14.jpg" />`

(one image tag for two links)

How to fix it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's because your regex has to be ungreedy. Just add the U flag at the end of your regex:

```
/(http:\/\/.+(png|jpeg|jpg|gif|bmp))/Ui
```

And it works!

Answer (score 0):

Your `.+` is matching too much. You need to make it match as little as possible using `.+?`.

Now, you might run into some problems with images which contain the string, eg, `gif` (eg, in `example.com/gift.png`, only `example.com/gif` would match)… But that can partially be fixed by suffixing the expression with `\b` (word break) or `\s` (whitespace). You'll have to experiment to see what works for your data.

Answer (score 0):

Use non-greedy matching:

```
/(http:\/\/.+?(png|jpeg|jpg|gif|bmp))/i
```

`.+?` will only match for the first `(png|jpg|...`